# Setting delete rule to "Set null" in one to many relationship using code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have two entities which have one to many relationships

```
public class Brand{

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Product{ get; set; }
}

public class Product{

    public virtual Brand Brand{ get; set; }
}

>  modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>()
>                 .HasMany(x => x.Product)
>                 .WithOptional(e => e.Brand)
>                 .HasForeignKey(e => e.BrandSKU);
```

Want to set the Delete Rule as "Set null",  which i am not being able to find out how can i achieve the same using code first.

Comment: when the migration context is generated, there is an option for on-cascade delete = true as default, changing that could solve the problem

Comment: Thanks Arun for the help, can you please mention how can i set null on-cascade delete.

Comment: If the field support null, I this you can specific here it self.. Don't have experience